# Create a filtered list from a list with a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a function which creates a new List from a List with a for loop. In the new List should just be int and float in a range from 1 to 49.

Like:

```
filter_list[2,3,55,"test",10]=[2,3,10]
```

how can i create such a list with a for loop?

Edit:
My code so far:

```
def filter_list(elements):
    list = []
    for i in elements:
        if i in range(1,50):
            list.append(i)
    return list
```

but when i want to proof if its int or float with

```
isinstance(i,str)
```

it does not work probably

Comment: Procuding and testing code would be a start. If you happen to have tried something and it is faulty, post the code in your question. SO 
is about fixing _your_ Code - not providing code to solve your tasks. 
Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @PatrickArtner sorry, added a Code above

Answer (score 0):

You could use `filter`:

```
def filter_list(l):
    return list(filter(lambda x: (isinstance(x, int) or isinstance(x, float)) and 1 <= x <= 49, l))
```

For python2, you won't need to convert the result of `filter` to a list. But for python3, you'll need the conversion.

And you'll call it this way:

```
>>> filter_list([2,3,55,"test",10])
[2, 3, 10]
```

Or simply use a list comprehension:

```
def filter_list(l):
    return [x for x in l if (isinstance(x, int) or isinstance(x, float)) and 1 <= x <= 49]
```

Comment: Do you know a solution without Lambda?

Comment: Please refrain from answering questions that do not show even a modicum of effort put into solving it themselfs. You are just providing their homework, they learn nothing from it - you helping them causes more harm then good.

Comment: You can condense your list comp range check like so: `[e for e in l if (isinstance(e,int) or isinstance(e,float)) and 1 <= e <= 49]` - using `isinstance` instead of `type` would make it work for things that are derived from `int` or `float` as well. `type` works only for `int` and `float` itself. If you want to keep `type()` you can go even shorter:  `return list(filter(lambda x: type(x) in (int, float) and 1 <= x <= 49, l))`